# MS Word Format Data Series Line Cap Type

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office

I'm creating charts in Microsoft Word using C#.  I can successfully do most of my formatting through code.  However, I still need some help.  Please see the image below.

[image: Format Data Series Screenshot]

This is a screen shot of the Format Data Series window when you right-click on a chart line and select Format Data Series.
The only 2 properties that are giving me trouble are Cap Type and Join Type.  The VBA recorder doesn't even record anything when you change them.

I need to be able to change the cap type on the Line through C#.  Does anyone have any ideas??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, `Cap type` and `Join type` are not exposed through the object model in Word / Excel. The only way I can think of to accomplish this is using `SendKeys` in VBA but I don't know off the top of my head how that would be implemented in C# - it's not trivial but there may be some implementations out there. Even if you get that working, though, I'd not recommend goint that route - Word 2007, Word 2010 and the upcoming Word 2013 all have somewhat different UI-s so the keystrokes that need to be sent would be different. Users could also press keys just while you're trying send keys to the Word instance. And then you'd have to deal with charts having multiple series, etc.

Comment: I'm sorry it didn't work out for you. I had a lot of headaches when I used to work on automating Word - it has a lot of features but it's always just "almost there" - I always ran into things that were near impossible to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a chart in advance that has Flat, and use VBA to only edit the line end coordinates, so styles remain untouched.